# Application Insights 2.0 makes IntelliTrace stop working

Tags: azure-application-insights, intellitrace

As soon as I install Application Insights 2.0, my IntelliTrace stops working. I have isolated to Application Insights, 100% sure.

Does anyone else have this problem?

[image: INTELLITRACE NOT WORKING]

Comment: 100% confirmed. Just created a blank solution, updated to Application Insights 2.0, now IntelliTrace is dead.

Comment: what specific version of application insights sdk and what version of visual studio?  did you update the web sdk but not he core sdk?  or did you update all of them?  also, what version of the application insights tools in VS do you have? (tools menu, extensions+updaes, find either "Application Insights Tools for Visual studio" or "Developer Analytics Tools")

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015.2, with Application Insights Tools 5.202.60415.1, and I updated all the Application Insights packages (core + others) in nuget to 2.0

Comment: If you want, I cant send you a demo project

Comment: that's super odd.  it *might* not be specific to the project then, it might be your date/locale settings?  instead of the whole demo project, if you debug it, can you send me some of the debug output from the SDK?  it would be lines like `Application Insights Telemetry: [blah]` that appear in the output window?  email is jgardner at microsoft.  we can go more in depth via email and then i can update the answer here.

Comment: Funny. It is working today. Maybe you guys did something at your end! Thanks for the help

Comment: to satisfy my curiosity, can you still grab timestamps out of the output lines?  i have a feeling that there's some kind of race condition in the sdk that *sometimes* it uses a different timestamp format when writing things out.  if you ever see it again let me know so we can track it down.

Answer (score 0):

The 2.0+ versions of the application insights sdks send timestamps for the event data in UTC, when previous versions of the sdks sent the times in local time.   The Application Insights tools in Visual Studio parse that date, and end up telling the debugger that there's a new event that took place either hours in the past or hours in the future, so the diagnostic tools gets... confused.

This was fixed in newer versions of the Application Insights tools, [(might be?) fixed in 4.3](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=733356) if you are on VS 2015 Update 1, or in the current 5.2+ versions that are [available from the gallery for VS 2015 Update 2](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/82367b81-3f97-4de1-bbf1-eaf52ddc635a). (as of update2, the extension is also auto-updatable from the gallery as well)

Comment: I have the 5.2+ version and the bug it still there :/. Also, I am using VS 2015.2. I downgraded my App Insights to 1.x and IntelliTrace is working again